# Can GDPR violations lead to piercing of the corporate veil?

Tags: gdpr

Does GDPR have any clauses that hint at piercing of the corporate veil?

Can GDPR violations lead to piercing of the corporate veil?

Answer (score 1):

> Does GDPR have any clauses that hint at piercing of the corporate veil?

[No.](https://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/?uri=CELEX:02016R0679-20160504)

> Can GDPR violations lead to piercing of the corporate veil?

It doesn't seem so, but there haven't yet been [any rulings by the ECJ on the GDPR](https://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/ALL/?uri=CELEX:32016R0679#PPLinked_Contents) (see the "affected by case" section), so who knows?